# Content is published either on filesystem or database but not published on both

Tags: publishing, 2013

I need to configured storage config file for both database and filesystem, but when I set up the value of defaultStorageId in ItemTypes node as "defaultId" then it only published data into the broker database whether I am publishing page, and if I changed the value of defaultStorageId as filesystem then it only published data into the file system and also creates the few other folders like binarymeta , binaryvariant , componentmeta etc .

So my requirement is that if I publish a page, usercontrol etc then it should published to the filesystem and also put the detail of the page into the broker. I am attaching the database and filesystem part of my storage config file here for reference.

```
<Storages>        
    <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL"  Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" defaultStorage="true">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" 
             CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
          <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                      <Property Name="serverName" Value="WIN-IJFCS71234"/>
                      <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
                      <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_dev"/>
                      <Property Name="user" Value="xyz"/>
                      <Property Name="password" Value="abc"/>
           </DataSource>
      </Storage>
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" 
    Id="fileStorage" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
    <Root Path="c:\tridion\tork"/>
</Storage>                  
</Storages>     
<Transaction Timeout="240000" MonitorInterval="5000"/>
</Global>

  <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="fileStorage" cached="false">     
    <publication Id="16" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="fileStorage"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="fileStorage"/>
        </publication>
   </ItemTypes>
```

Comment: why do you need the page to be in the broker and on the filesystem?

Comment: As page should be published on file system and at the same page information get updated in broker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 2 storage configurations in your cd_storage_conf.xml, then bind the item types to the storage you want to use.

There's a good example of that [here](http://code.google.com/p/kickstart-tridion-environment/source/browse/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/ConfigSamples/preview-web/cd_storage_conf.xml)

In your example, you're binding ALL item types AND pages to the same storage, which is kind of redundant. The typical configuration scenario is "Everything in database, except for pages & binaries which go to the file system".

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="sqlserver" cached="false">
  <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="filesystem" />
  <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="filesystem" />
</ItemTypes>
```

Do you really need to have a different behavior per publication? I would normally tend to avoid one-offs in cd_storage_conf simply due to cost of maintenance...

Comment: As I mentioned in question that if I give the "defaultId" value in defaultStorageId attribute(rest values are same for Items) then pages get published only in database instead of filesystem but that is not happening

I tried to do even with the above configuration but then its only published data in broker where as in that kind of configuration the page should published in the file system

Comment: Can you try removing the `defaultFileSystem` and `defaultStorage` attributes from the `storage` element for your fileStorage storage? I always remove those (though I can't really remember why) :)

Comment: Working now......after removing these attributes, I got this kind of storage configuration from the tridion installer

Comment: Yeah, I have to do something about those confusing defaults... My apologies.