# Categories and Keywords Publishing

Tags: content-manager, 2011-sp1, deployer

I am having problems publishing out Categories and Keywords from our production CMS to the production website. I am able to publish out pages and components out to production though.

Our staging site also uses the production CMS and I am able to successfully publish out categories and keywords to staging along with pages and components. The error that I am receiving is:

Polling for notification for destination: GZooXEYT4LDvTdo3hx4K7w== has exceeded polling attempts for transaction: tcm:0-156845-66560

I've already previously removed jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl.jar.

It seems to get stuck in the Committing Deployment phase when going to production and will then eventually timeout.

For the production storage part of cd_storage_conf.xml it looks like most of it is going to the DB:

```
                        <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="" />
                                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                                    <Property Name="user" Value="" />
                                    <Property Name="password" Value="" />
                            </DataSource>
                    </Storage>
```

The above matches the staging server with the exception of the database settings of course.

There is one filesystem path part of the storage setup though:

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
                            <Root Path="/data/webapps" />
                    </Storage>
```

This is the ItemTypes for Production:

```
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="true">
            <Item typeMapping="Query" storageId="defaultdb"/>

    <Item typeMapping="BinaryMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="BinaryVariant" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentLinkClick" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentationMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentVisit" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="DynamicLinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ItemMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="LinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>

    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
```

This is the item types for staging:

```
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

            <Item typeMapping="Query" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="BinaryMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="BinaryVariant" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentLinkClick" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentationMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentVisit" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="DynamicLinkInfo" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ItemMeta" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Item typeMapping="LinkInfo" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>

    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
```

Chris,

I added in the item type as directed but the publishing still failed for the same polling reasons. I've verified that the user name in the storage file can access the database server with the credentials that are in there from another database server w/in the same domain. I've also verified the location of the license file and that the firewall is not an issue. I only found one jdbc jar file on the deployer server and it is jdbcpool.jar. Are there any others that I should be looking for?

Thanks,

In the core log I am seeing that the production deployer is having problems connecting to the Cache Channel Service. Could this be related?

Also the below text is what I see in the deployer log. I don't see anything failing.

```
    2014-09-03 14:26:09,793 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: meta.xml processing as normal file request
2014-09-03 14:26:09,800 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - Retrieving list of files from location: /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming with extension.progress 
2014-09-03 14:26:09,800 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - Found 0 files in folder /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming
2014-09-03 14:26:09,802 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - Retrieving list of files from location: /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming with extension.Content.zip 
2014-09-03 14:26:09,802 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - Found 0 files in folder /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming
2014-09-03 14:26:09,825 INFO  HTTPSReceiverServlet - Persisting received TransportPackage: tcm_0-156873-66560.Content.zip
2014-09-03 14:26:10,537 INFO  ContentLocationHandler - Found 1 new packages for processing in /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming
2014-09-03 14:26:10,538 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Retrieved Deployment package from queue with transactionId: tcm:0-156873-66560 and type: CONTENT
2014-09-03 14:26:10,538 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Starting running transaction thread: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,539 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Exclusive lock on Deployment package acquired for transaction tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,539 INFO  TransactionManager - Starting handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-156873-66560 with type: CONTENT
2014-09-03 14:26:10,540 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Starting executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,541 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployer Prepare Phase for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,541 DEBUG UnzipWorker - zipLocation = /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming/tcm_0-156873-66560.Content.zip
2014-09-03 14:26:10,542 INFO  UnzipWorker - Starting unzipping for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560 and package: /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming/tcm_0-156873-66560.Content.zip
2014-09-03 14:26:10,545 INFO  UnzipWorker - Moving Deployment Package to unzip folder for transactionId: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,547 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Processing Phase for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: PRE_PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: pre-processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: pre-processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: pre-processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,552 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy
2014-09-03 14:26:10,554 DEBUG TCDLEngine - TCDL: Using built-in tag registry
2014-09-03 14:26:10,554 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy
2014-09-03 14:26:10,555 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy
2014-09-03 14:26:10,555 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy
2014-09-03 14:26:10,555 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy
2014-09-03 14:26:10,556 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy
2014-09-03 14:26:10,557 DEBUG TCDLEngine - TCDL: Using built-in tag registry
2014-09-03 14:26:10,557 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy
2014-09-03 14:26:10,557 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processor with action: Deploy in phase: processing for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,557 INFO  Processor - Modules will now process package [TransportPackage transactionId=tcm:0-156873-66560]
2014-09-03 14:26:10,558 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Deploying tcd:pub[0]/pub[19].
2014-09-03 14:26:10,558 DEBUG HandlerFactory - Retrieving typeHandler for itemURI: tcd:pub[0]/pub[19]
2014-09-03 14:26:10,558 DEBUG TaxonomyDeploy - Processing section Taxonomies
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 INFO  TaxonomyDeploy - Finished transformation of RDF
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Deploying tcd:pub[19]/taxonomy[176].
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 DEBUG HandlerFactory - Retrieving typeHandler for itemURI: tcd:pub[19]/taxonomy[176]
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 INFO  Processor - All modules successfully processed package [TransportPackage transactionId=tcm:0-156873-66560]
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: POST_PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: post-processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,685 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: post-processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,686 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: post-processing
2014-09-03 14:26:10,686 INFO  ProcessingPhase - We have 2 transaction items waiting for commit.
2014-09-03 14:26:10,686 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Persisting transaction log for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560.
2014-09-03 14:26:10,686 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Persisting deployment transaction information: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,723 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,723 INFO  PreCommitPhase - Executing phase: pre-transaction for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,723 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: pre-transaction
2014-09-03 14:26:10,724 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: pre-transaction
2014-09-03 14:26:10,724 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: pre-transaction
2014-09-03 14:26:10,725 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Loading deployment transaction information: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:10,726 INFO  PreCommitPhase - Executing workers for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560 with 2 Workers
2014-09-03 14:26:10,727 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.PublicationWorker@4e7016ff this is worker 1 of: 2
2014-09-03 14:26:10,741 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.PublicationWorker@4e7016ff took: 14
2014-09-03 14:26:10,741 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.TaxonomyWorker@4ee42af2 this is worker 2 of: 2
2014-09-03 14:26:13,779 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.TaxonomyWorker@4ee42af2 took: 3038
2014-09-03 14:26:13,780 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:13,781 INFO  CommitPhase - Committing transaction: tcm:0-156873-66560
2014-09-03 14:26:14,801 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: meta.xml processing as normal file request
2014-09-03 14:26:14,806 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: tcm_0-156873-66560.state.xml processing as normal file request
2014-09-03 14:26:14,806 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - File found at /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming/tcm_0-156873-66560.state.xml for tcm_0-156873-66560.state.xml
2014-09-03 14:26:19,808 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: meta.xml processing as normal file request
2014-09-03 14:26:19,811 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: tcm_0-156873-66560.state.xml processing as normal file request
2014-09-03 14:26:19,812 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - File found at /usr/local/Tridion-CDS/incoming/tcm_0-156873-66560.state.xml for tcm_0-156873-66560.state.xml
2014-09-03 14:26:24,818 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: meta.xml processing as normal file request
```

Comment: You need to check the CM box's Event Viewer and CD Deployer logs (see log's location in logback.xml) to see exactly which module is failing.

Comment: Check the cd_storage_conf on the Deployer.  See if the Category / Keyword bindings are set to DB or filesystem.  Also, compare the storage_conf between your staging and production deployers to see if they have different bindings.  I assume the only diff should be the DB / Filesystem settings.

Comment: Publishing Categories and Keywords requires you to configure the Taxonomy type mapping (they can only go in the database, there is no filesystem support for them), can you share some details about your `cd_storage_conf.xml`, specifically the item type mappings?

Comment: You will need to check the cd_core.log next to the Deployer log, since it appears that storage is going wrong and the Deployer doesn't store itself (it uses the Broker for the actual storage, so the error messages will end up in a different log).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

> I only found one jdbc jar file on the deployer server and it is
>   jdbcpool.jar. Are there any others that I should be looking for?

The answer to this is 'Yes'. You should also have the **sqljdbc4.jar** in the lib folder of your Deployer (as you are using SQL Server).

This is covered in the Database client section of the [Content Delivery prerequisites](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_97BB43152C35488C843676F335B78099) page in the online documentation (login required).

### So, why are Pages and Components (with Metadata) publishing, you ask?

Your Pages & Components will continue to publish, if they do not have any Metadata that would need adding to the database.

Alternatively, if you have a `filesystem` `Storage` element in your cd_storage_conf.xml file with the `defaultFilesystem` attribute set to `true` (as below), then it will use this location as a fallback location, rather than the database storage, if your license for database storage has expired or is missing.

However, as well as handling an invalid license, I suspect that your Pages and Components may be continuing to publish, and their metadata is going in to this directory on the filesystem (rather than in to the database).

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
    <Root Path="c:\temp\data" />
</Storage>
```

You cannot publish the Taxonomy to the filesystem, that may be why this is failing.

You could check this by looking for files being created in that directory (as configured in **your** `cd_storage_conf.xml`)

**UPDATE:** I have just seen that you said "There is **one** filesystem path part of the storage setup" (and this does not have `defaultStorage="true"`). Therefore, I suspect that Pages and Components are continuing to publish because they don't have any Metadata.

### If you do already have sqljdbc4.jar...

If you do have the **sqljdbc4.jar** in the lib folder of your Deployer, then you may want to try removing the `defaultFileSystem` and `defaultStorage` attributes from the `Storage` element for your main `filesystem` storage completely. This was suggested by Nuno here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/5118/71

Comment: That worked!! I was able to publish out the categories and keywords successfully. It was the last step provided here that was provided by Nuno as everything else was in place already including the sqljdbc4.jar file. Thank you for the assistance everyone!!!

Comment: @Joe - That's great news. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

As per Bart,

> Publishing Categories and Keywords requires you to configure the
>   Taxonomy type mapping (they can only go in the database, there is no
>   filesystem support for them)

You must either specify `defaultdb` as the `defaultStorageId` like:

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
```

Or add the `ItemType` to specifically send Taxonomy items to the Broker database like:

```
<Item typeMapping="Taxonomy" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
```

Once either of these are setup, and the deployer has been restarted republish and verify if items begin appearing in the Broker database.

If not, review the log files, with the most likely causes of failure being:

- Cannot communicate with database server due to firewall/miss configuration
- Incorrect user credentials or grant permissions
- Invalid or missing license file in the deployer
- Missing JDBC JAR file